# how to create new partition in unallocated disk

Tags: macos, mac

how to create new partition in the red-arrow pointing unallocated disk

And I don't want to lose any data in existing COMMON partition.

I haven't made any copy of common partition.

[image]

Comment: Have you made a backup of the COMMON partition?

Comment: What OS is this? Mac or Linux?

Comment: @poc You can do it with diskutil from command line. Duplicate question with [this one in stackexchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63130/create-new-partition-in-unallocated-space-with-diskutil).

Answer (score 0):

In *Mac OS*, just resize it and then you will be able to create a new partition out of the free space.

If you want to move it to the back of the disk, then use `parted` or `gparted` by loading from, let's say [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is highlight the free space like you have in the screenshot and click the plus sign at the bottom of the partition map.  It won't touch the common partition at all.  When you hit the apply button, it will confirm this.

Comment: NOT if the drive is MBR, only if it's GUID